# How to clear the HttpOnly flag on Cookies?

Tags: c#, http, cookies, ormlite-servicestack

I seem to be having the reverse problem to a lot of people.  Many questions have looked at why their cookies lose the `HttpOnly` setting.  I am trying to work out why mine keeps hanging around.

I am writing a proxy service using `ServiceStack` to allow jQuery ajax calls to work cross-domain with a server that does not implement JSONP or CORS (don't worry, this is actually a legitimate project). When a response containing a cookie is received, I copy it across to the Response object, as follows:

Incoming cookie:

```
Set-Cookie: MYAPI=8579...05B1; expires=Thu, 10-Apr-2014 13:08:18 GMT; path=/
```

As you can see, no HttpOnly flag.  I then copy the cookie across as follows:

```
var cookies = client.CookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri(apiUrl));
foreach (Cookie cookie in cookies)
{
    cookie.HttpOnly = false;
    cookie.Domain = "";
    Response.Cookies.AddCookie(cookie);
}
```

And then return the response. All the data comes through correctly, but the cookie ends up as:

```
Set-Cookie: MYAPI=8579...05B1; expires=Thu, 10-Apr-2014 13:08:18 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
```

I have set my web.config with the following:

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="false"/>
```

Any ideas as to why the `HttpOnly` flag is being set, and how to get around it?  I did read somewhere that `ServiceStack` sets `HttpOnly` by default, but couldn't see how to un-set it.

Comment: Further, according to https://github.com/stabbylambda/ServiceStack/commit/2fe1fefa338d3aac7aed6d7161dc0e2191dd52dd, ServiceStack looks like it is set to use ONLY HttpOnly cookies.  I understand the desire to set HttpOnly by default, but wouldn't this be ultimately at the discretion of the developer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A configuration setting, `AllowNonHttpOnlyCookies` has been added to ServiceStack to cope with this situation. The setting defaults to `false` (enforcing `HttpOnly` cookies).